# How to filter an array of objects to remove elements based on condition in MongoDB aggregate?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a collection of documents `ChatRooms` in MongoDB that has this (simplified) structure:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('4654'),
  messages: [
    {
      user: ObjectId('1234'),
      sentAt: ISODate('2022-03-01T00:00:00.000Z')
    },
    {
      user: ObjectId('1234'),
      sentAt: ISODate('2022-03-02T00:00:00.000Z')
    },
    {
      user: ObjectId('8888'),
      sentAt: ISODate('2022-03-03T00:00:00.000Z')
    },
  ]
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to filter the `messages` array inside the `aggregate` pipeline in order to get an array where the `userId` is presend just once. The result I'm looking for is (or something similar but the array shouldn't have two elements with the same `user` id):

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('4654'),
  messages: [
    {
      user: ObjectId('1234'),
      sentAt: ISODate('2022-03-01T00:00:00.000Z')
    },
    {
      user: ObjectId('8888'),
      sentAt: ISODate('2022-03-03T00:00:00.000Z')
    },
  ]
}
```

Is such a thing possible even?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in several different ways, here is an example of how to achieve this using the `$reduce` operator:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      messages: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$messages",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $in: [
                  "$$this.user",
                  "$$value.user"
                ]
              },
              "$$value",
              {
                "$concatArrays": [
                  "$$value",
                  [
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/af01h5MrB6V)